# Getter and Setter in generic interface - is this possible?

Tags: c#, generics

Still learning my ways around C# generics... is it possible to achieve this functionality?

```
public interface ISetting<T>
{
    void SetSettings(T obj);
    // myTypeHere GetSettings(T obj);
}

public class RadDockSetting : ISetting<CormantRadDock>
{
    public RadDockSetting()
    {
    }

    public RadDockSetting GetSettings(CormantRadDock dock)
    {
    }

    public void SetSettings(CormantRadDock dock)
    {
    }
 }
```

I realize this is a counter-intuitive way to be using a Getter -- shouldn't have to pass anything to it. What I'm doing is creating an object, RadDockSetting, that stores the relevant properties of the CormantRadDock -- and then returns the 'got' settings.

GetSettings is *currently* a static method, but I realize this will need to be refactored in order to allow implementing a getter from the interface. Maybe once this occurs the 'weirdness' of the getter will fall away?

So, a little background on all of this:

I started with a class that had a lot of 'copy/pasted' functions. These functions were in charge of saving and removing controls from a manager. When I realized this I set out trying to make these functions more generic. I succeeded, with SO's help, in making remove generic.

For reference, here is remove:

```
public static void Remove<T>(string controlID) where T: new()
{
    Logger.InfoFormat("Removing control {0}", controlID);
    T states = RadControlStates.GetStates<T>();
    (states as IDictionary).Remove(controlID);
    RadControlStates.SetStates<T>(states);
}
```

and it is called like so: `RadControlSave.Remove<SerializableDictionary<string, RadPaneSetting>>(ID);`

Now, I am trying to extend this genericness to the rest of the methods -- the savers. Here's how one of these methods looks currently:

```
public static void SavePane(CormantRadPane pane)
{
    Logger.InfoFormat("Saving pane {0}", pane.ID);
    RadPaneSetting paneSettings = RadPaneSetting.GetSettings(pane);
    SerializableDictionary<string, RadPaneSetting> paneStates = RadControlStates.GetStates<SerializableDictionary<string, RadPaneSetting>>();

    bool paneIsKnown = paneStates.ContainsKey(paneSettings.ID);

    if (paneIsKnown)
    {
        Logger.Debug("Pane is known. Overwriting data.");
        paneStates[paneSettings.ID] = paneSettings;
    }
    else
    {
        Logger.Debug("Pane is unknown. Saving data.");
        paneStates.Add(paneSettings.ID, paneSettings);
    }

    RadControlStates.SetStates<SerializableDictionary<string, RadPaneSetting>>(paneStates);
}
```

At the start of this code block there is a call to "RadPaneSetting.GetSettings(pane)".

RadPaneSettings implements the ISettings interface. Here is ISetting's setter being used.

```
/// <summary>
/// Recreates a dashboard control based off of its settings.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"> The type of control to be recreated. </typeparam>
/// <param name="settings"> The known settings needed to recreate the control.</param>
/// <returns> The recreated control. </returns>
public static T Recreate<T>(ISetting<T> settings) where T : new()
{
    T _control = new T();
    settings.SetSettings(_control);
    Logger.DebugFormat("Recreated control {0}", (_control as Control).ID);
    return _control;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Let me add some more code, then!

Comment: You could return a `ISetting<T>` there. But think again what you really want to achieve here.

Comment: I would think that GetSettings() and SetSettings() would be methods on CormantRadDoc, *not* on RadDockSettings.  I have a dock, what are the settings? `RadDockSettings settings = mydock.GetSettings()` and with `{ get; set; }` defined that could just be `settings = mydock.settings`

Comment: I really agree with your comment, Stephen. Something has felt off with this bit of code for some time now, but I hadn't sat down and really THOUGHT about it. I'm going to look into this for a bit. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you just need to add another generic parameter here

```
public interface ISetting<T1, T2>
{
    void SetSettings(T1 obj);
    T2 GetSettings(T1 obj);
}

public class RadDockSettings : ISetting<CormantRadDock, RadDockSetting>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your question is not very clear but do you need a property:

```
public interface ISetting<T>
{
    T Setting { get; set; }
}

public class RadDockSetting : ISetting<CormantRadDock>
{
    public CormantRadDock Setting { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have would work if you define another generic parameter (as @jaredPar pointed out).  You may want to consider using Extension Methods rather than the class approach, though.  It would allow you to have a "cleaner" API for getting the settings.

Sample:

```
public static class RadDockExtensions
{
    public static RadDockSetting GetSettings(this CormantRadDock dock)
    {
        // Implementation
    }
}
```

Or if you want something more generic

```
public static class RadDockExtensions
{
    public static U GetSettings<T,U>(this T dock)
    {
        // Implementation
    }
}
```

Though in this case you would need to add some constraints to actually create the implementation

It's not entirely clear to me what the purpose of the `SetSettings` method is, since you appear to be sending in the same object your sending to `GetSettings`.

In both cases you would use the above code like this:

```
RadDockSetting mySettings = myDock.GetSettings();
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the detailed reply! I went ahead and added a lot more background information to my question. I believe I'm doing something fundamentally/logically incorrect and it is just now showing itself because of how this is breaking down. I will take a read on extension methods, however. Thanks!

Comment: Yes you did :).  It actually makes more sense now that there is additional context.  Take a look at what Extension Methods give you.  They are compiler sugar, certainly, but they can make calling the sort of code you have a little less noisy, which is always a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

hmmmm might have missed the point.

but why would a settings class have a getSettings call? would it just return `this`?

The set takes a dock to initialise the instance, then get is merely the instance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you want to do.
Maybe an extension method could do the trick rather than a method inside the interface ISetting... something like that :

```
public static T GetSettings<T,C>(this T t, C c) where T : ISetting<C>
{
    return t;
}
```

Hope this helps...